# How to fetch row one by one in sql

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server

I am fetching table-names from particular database like this

```
SELECT name FROM sys.Tables where name like 'some pattern'

Output : 
Name
sampletable_123,
sampletable_456,
sample_789.
```

It can return more than one row like above output. How to fetch row one by one?

Because I want to find out column-name/date from obtained table-name. If date is less than current date, I want to drop that table.

```
select top 1 Udate from  sampletable_123
where Udate < convert(varchar(10),getdate(),101)

delete table sampletable_123.
```

How to do that?

Comment: Lets say you have such a script. What happens when you cannot drop the table because of fk references? Or what happens when the fk reference table conditions are not the same as the one from the first table?

Comment: Why do you create all those sample-tables?

Comment: I want to drop table.Table does not have fk references

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks SubqueryCrunch and Sergio Internicola for ur help.@Sergio Internicola, ur logic is right.I think curser take time.I modified SubqueryCrunch's query.It is working fine with me.

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(4000)

SET @SQL = ' '

SELECT 
    @SQL += 'IF  EXISTS(SELECT TOP 1 udate FROM ' + name + ' WHERE DATEDIFF(day,udate,GETDATE()) != 0)
    DROP TABLE ' + name +' '
FROM sys.Tables 
where name like 'tbl_%'

PRINT @SQL
EXEC sp_executesql @SQL
```

Comment: Cursors take time on huge tables, but if you deal with a few dozens of rows, it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

This will generate dynamic sql script which you can preview and if those are the tables you want to delete you can use EXEC on it.

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @SQL = ''

SELECT 
    @SQL += 'IF (OBJECT_ID(' + name + ') IS NOT NULL AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT TOP 1 uDate FROM ' + name + ' WHERE DATEDIFF(day,uDate,GETDATE()) != 0)
    DROP TABLE ' + name + CHAR(10)
FROM sys.Tables 
where name like 'some pattern'

PRINT @SQL --print will show you the delete query that was generated
--keep in mind that print wont be able to print the whole query if its bigger than 4000 characters
--but exec will still run it
--another way to preview it is to select the query because select has no limit it's just on one row
--EXEC(@SQL)
```

Comment: No SubqueryCrunch,not like that..After getting table,I want to find date from that table,if that date is less than cureent date, drop that table

Comment: the create date  of the table ? I do believe that you can modify my example for your needs :)

Comment: I think ,curser is good option to fetch record(tablename) one by one and to do further processing

Comment: You can do this without a cursor just tell me which date you want to check and ill help you with your query.

Comment: Table has udate column.Table contain multiple record.I want fetch top one udate.If udate is less current date,Drop that table..

Comment: I updated my answer. Please tell me if i this is not what you want.

Comment: Hello SubqueryCrunch ,thanks for ur reply.I think u forgot to set the value for @SQL.I used ur query and asigened select query(from select clause to where name like pattern match) but I am getting error : Invalid column name

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90601/discussion-between-subquerycrunch-and-jui-test).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a cursor on the above select, and fetch one row at a time.
For each row, you can retrieve the first row of the table and decide to drop it or not.

```
DECLARE @TABLES CURSOR
DECLARE @MYNAME VARCHAR(100)

SET @TABLES CURSOR FOR
   SELECT name FROM sys.Tables WHERE name LIKE 'sample%'

OPEN @TABLES

WHILE 1 = 1 BEGIN -- INFINITE LOOP
   FETCH NEXT FROM @TABLES INTO @MYNAME
   IF @@FETCH_STATUS <> 0 BREAK
   IF EXISTS(SELECT TOP 1 Udate FROM @MYNAME WHERE Udate < CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),101))
      DROP TABLE @MYNAME
END
```